# make browsing list for every vistor depend on php session

Tags: php, html, session

i try make browsing list for every vistor depend on php session

when the vistor vist any post add id in session

and make foreach to display all posts

its work good in localhost but its not work in the website

its display only one post id in the website

```
<?php
if($_POST['delsession1'])
{
    unset($_SESSION['idm']);
}else{
    $_SESSION['idm'][] .= $topicid; 
    $ii=1;
    foreach($_SESSION["idm"] as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val > 0)
        {?>
            <?php
            if($langs === 'en'){
            $vid=intval($val);
            ?>
            <div class="w3-padding new_topics_title"><?=$ii++;?>. <a href="<?=$langs;?>/<?=intval($val);?>"><?=Title($en_database,'topic',$vid,$langs);?></a></div>
            <?
            }
            else{?>
            <div class="w3-padding new_topics_title"><?=$ii++;?>. <a href="<?=$langs;?>/<?=intval($val);?>"><?=Title($all_database,'topic',$vid,$langs);?></a></div>
            <?}
            ?>
        <?}
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array push instead of .=

```
 $_SESSION['idm'] = array();
 array_push($_SESSION['idm'],$topicid);
```